# What is the difference between the navigation and menu widgets

Tags: magento2, javascript, menu, navigation, widgets

I've just noticed Magento 2 has two widgets that sound very similar, [the menu widget](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_menu.html) and [the navigation widget](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_navigation.html).

They are both customised versions of the Query UI Menu widget and they both use the same source - [`lib/web/mage/menu.js`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/lib/web/mage/menu.js)

**What differences are there between these widgets?**